# Laravel installer are inside .composer/vendor/bin directory and I tried to run laravel command but it gives error

Tags: laravel

Laravel installer are inside .composer/vendor/bin directory and I tried to run Laravel command but it gives error "sh: 22: Laravel: not found"
I am using Ubuntu as a OS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add composer bin dir to your PATH environment variable.

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Comment: I have run the above export command but laravel still not works.